# Enumerate replaces uppercase letter 'A' with numbers?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

When I try to do:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(A1)]
\item blah
\item blah blah
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I get the output of:

```
(11) blah
(22) blah blah
```

It seems to work fine with other uppercase letters, but I specifically need the capital letter 'A' for this list. How can I fix it?

Comment: Read the documentation: "however the tokens A a I i 1 must be inside a { } group if they are not to be taken as special."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is indeed a bit surprising*, as I would have expected it to be:

> (A1) blah
>
> (B2) blah blah

I would have expected this, as the input of `\begin{enumerate}[...]` introduces the counting variable for your list and in fact you gave it two counting variables.

The possible active characters here are

- `I` for capital Roman numbers
- `i` for small Roman numbers
- `1` for Arabic numbers
- `A` for capital letters
- `a` for small letters

The last active character in your command wins. I do not know where the second number comes from. 
All other characters get ignored such as your parenthesis or the "other uppercase letters".

If you want `enumerate` to ignore one of the 5 active characters, you have to wrap it in curly braces.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{enumerate}[({A}1)]
        \item blah
        \item blah blah
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*I contacted the maintainer of this package and here is Mr. Carlisle comment:

> You get 11, 22 because each of the special letters gets turned into
>   `\theenumi` and defines that to be (say) `\alph{enumi}`. So for `A1` you get
>   `\theenumi\theenumi` and define `\theenumi` to be `\alph` then `\arabic` so
>   the latter definition wins but you still get two counters printed.

Comment: `\begin{enumerate}[label=(A\arabic*)]` would be the syntax with `enumitem`. Clearer and less error prone.